# Position input elements on the right of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have some difficulties positioning two elements on the right side of the page. Strangely the suggested answers of similar questions did not work at all or gave poor results, but most of them were correct if I used simpler elements like text-fields for example.

The view is: 
[image: Image of a Filter text box]
Here's what I have:

```css
input, select, textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
  text-size-adjust: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="searchText">
</div>
```

I have tried to adjust the position with `float: right` and by using the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Can you put more code?

Comment: More code like what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have somehow set your `input-group` to have a fixed width, instead of the default 100%. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about positioning.

In any event, bootstrap has a `pull-right` class you can use in order to float elements to the right. Just add it to your first div.

```css
.input-group {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group pull-right">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="searchText">
</div>
```

Have a read about this on the official docs, [**here**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

Comment: Lol that easy? I have spent all morning trying to fix this. Big thank you :)

Comment: No problem! The `pull-right` class is a bootstrap class and basically is just `float: right !important;`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search text" ng-model="searchText">
    </div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/5wyL6m54/)

or

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width:100px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/Dzhz4/396/)